# Figuring out number of dimension table(s) in my case of data warehouse

Tags: database, data-warehouse

I am a newbie to data warehousing so go easy on me please.

I am trying to figure out the number of dimensions in this case.

In my transaction database:

- I have a table which store Location Codes. Columns are `location_code int not null primary key, short_description varchar(10) not null, long_description varchar(100) not null`.
- I have a table which store Region Codes. Columns are `region_code int not null primary key, short_description varchar(10) not null, long_description varchar(100) not null`.
- I have a table which associates Locations and Regions. Columns are `assoc_id int not null primary key, location_code int not null, region_code int not null`. 1 Location belongs to only 1 Region.

In my data warehouse database user may want to lookup data by location or by region.

Now I am looking to create dimension table(s) in this case.

Wondering should I be creating 2 dimension tables (1 for Location and 1 for Region) this way?

- Create 1 dimension table for Location which also has Region with these columns: `location_code int not null primary key, location_short_description varchar(10) not null, location_long_description varchar(100) not null, region_code int not null, region_short_description varchar(10) not null, region_long_description varchar(100) not null`
- Create 1 dimension table for Region which also has Location with these columns: `region_code int not null primary key, region_short_description varchar(10) not null, region_long_description varchar(100) not null, location_code int not null, location_short_description varchar(10) not null, location_long_description varchar(100) not null`

OR should I be creating 4 dimension tables (1 for Location, 1 for Region, 1 for Location Region association, 1 for Region Location association) this way?

- Create 1 dimension table for Location with these columns: `location_code int not null primary key, short_description varchar(10) not null, long_description varchar(100) not null`
- Create 1 dimension table for Region with these columns: `region_code int not null primary key, short_description varchar(10) not null, long_description varchar(100) not null`
- Create 1 dimension table for Location Region association with these columns: `location_code int not null, region_code int not null`
- Create 1 dimension table for Region Location association with these columns: `region_code int not null, location_code int not null`

**Or is there another way which makes more sense? If yes please do tell**

In the Data Warehousing world, what type of relationship is this called and what is the standard way to handle it?

Thanks

Comment: Which is the business view of the process? To get a meaningful answer you should explain what "data" is and what are location and region. Are "data" for example Sales?  Is a location a geographical point which belong to a location? Could locations overlap?

Comment: @momobo data is hours worked in a specific location by all employees. So for example 1500 hours in Location L1 and 2400 hours in Location L2. A Location is geographical and locations cannot overlap. A Region has 1 or more Locations. 1 Location can belong to only 1 Region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would model the Location und Region in the same dimension (named according the business usage, for example D_Location, or D_Geography).

Hour number will be in the fact table and fact table F_Hour and D_Location will be connected with a surrogate key (a sequence in Oracle or an identity in Sql server).

All the descriptive column for Region and Location could happily live togheter in D_Location (of course Region will not be normalized but this is how it is normally done).

Comment: for a particular region how would you calculate hours?

Comment: select sum(hours) from F_Hour  join D_Location on F_Hour.keyLocation = D_Location.keyLocation where D_Location.Region = "Region 01"

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need to track association of location and region in the dimension tables. That association can be in the fact table.

I would create 2 dimension tables **D_Location** & **D_Region** and 1 fact table **F_Hour**.

**D_Location:**

```
location_code int not null primary key, short_description varchar(10) not null, long_description varchar(100) not null
```

**D_Region:**

```
region_code int not null primary key, short_description varchar(10) not null, long_description varchar(100) not null
```

**F_Hour:**

```
hour_id int not null primary key, location_code int not null, region_code int not null, hours decimal(10,2) not null
```

**F_Hour** would have 1 FK to **D_Location** and 1 FK to **D_Region**.

To get hours for a particular location_code (@location_code):

```
select h.location_code, l.short_description, l.long_description, sum(h.hours) 
from F_Hour h inner join D_Location l on h.location_code = l.location_code 
where h.location_code = @location_code 
group by h.location_code, l.short_description, l.long_description 
order by h.location_code
```

To get hours for a particular region_code (@region_code):

```
select h.region_code, r.short_description, r.long_description, sum(h.hours) 
from F_Hour h inner join D_Region r on h.region_code = r.region_code 
where h.region_code = @region_code 
group by h.region_code, r.short_description, r.long_description 
order by h.region_code
```

Does it make sense?

Comment: this look very similar to transaction database; can it be consider a data warehouse solution? I am not sure @momobo what are your views on this solution?

Comment: I think it works. Only, I would use only one dimension, and I would use surrogate keys.